# XPath How to compute 2 nodes and limit results for one

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

What would be the correct syntax to this :

```
//footer//a | (//a[not(//footer)] and position() <=200)
```

Use only //footer if exists, if not, find all //a that are not in //footer and limit this to 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close. The OR operator already handles your case - if footer contains no `<a>` nodes underneath it then second OR statement will be captured:

Using `python` and `parsel` (scrapy's html parser).

```py
>>> foo = Selector("<footer><a>text</a></footer>")
>>> bar = Selector("<div><a>text</a><a>text2</a><a>text3</a><a>text4</a></div>")
>>> foo.xpath("//footer//a | //a[position()<=2]").get()
'<a>text</a>'

>>> bar.xpath("//footer//a | //a[position()<=2]").extract()
['<a>text</a>', '<a>text2</a>']
```

Note: I used `2` instead of `200` for brevity.